# Start service on root user login

Tags: bash, fedora, systemd

I have two scripts, the second relying on the first:

`b_reb`:

This script creates a unit file for the second script. The `a_reb` service should only be started once the `root` user logs in, and should execute in the same session as `root`.

Here is the `b_reb` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Installing updates and other software
echo "Creating systemd unit file..."
cat << EOF > /usr/lib/systemd/system/a_reb.service
[Unit]
Description="Basic setup"

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=$(pwd)
Type=forking
ExecStart=/bin/bash $(pwd)/a_reb
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
echo "Enabling a_reb at startup..."
systemctl enable a_reb.service
reboot now
```

So the server reboots and root logs in. Now in the same session, `a_reb` should be executed by starting `a_reb.service`. I haven't made `a_reb` yet, but its contents are irrelevant.

For example:
Once root logs in, `a_reb` is executed and outputs a prompt for root to answer.

I hope I could explain myself properly. I am also open to other ways of doing this. The main idea is `b_reb` does something then reboots, whereafter `a_reb` runs as soon as root logs in after the reboot.

[UPDATE]

`b-reb` installs updates and required packages on the system. Afterwards it changes the `avahi-daemon` hostname to `.alocal`. The server then needs to reboot.

`a_reb` configures the installed software and does a domain join. The domain join looks like this:

```
# Get adm-user for domain-join
read -p 'adm username for domain-join: ' ADM
echo "Continuing as $ADM..."
realm join MYDOMAIN.LOCAL –U $ADM
```

This is why I need the script to run as root (I don't want to use sudo). We are 4 people that will be using this and we each have our own adm-user. `realm` will prompt for user password, so that's not necessary.

Comment: Please explain what is the real use case for this. Sounds like there are probably better (easier) ways to implement this.

Comment: @dawud added more info

Comment: It sounds like you'd be _way_ better off using a config management system like ansible, puppet, or chef for provisioning.

Comment: True, this is just as a proof-of-concept. Once we have have tested the installation process we will be looking at chef. @mattdm

Answer (score 1):

Your tasks are:

- b-reb installs updates and required packages on the system. Afterwards it changes the avahi-daemon hostname to .alocal. The server then needs to reboot.
- a_reb configures the installed software and does a domain join.

If you're going to complicate this at all, I would suggest using Ansible, Puppet, or Chef for real config management — and in fact, you note that you plan to automate this in the future. *Therefore*:

**Making this into a service is unnecessary complication.** And what you are trying to do with `a_reb` where the service reads from the console is bad practice. Just put your two shell scripts into `/usr/sbin` and instruct your four users to run them when the procedure (I'm not quite clear on this from your description) dicates.